# How to color specific parts of text div in D3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

**I want to make this:**
[image]

**This is what I have:**
[image]

**Question:** How do I color only specific parts of text div in D3?

I know in HTML, it would be `<text><span class="red">70,000</span>` people injured were white. But how do I do that in D3? B/c append only makes a child element. There's no way to append 2 span elements in a text element in 1 line...

**D3 code**

```
var size = [60,50,40,30];
    var fontColor = ["iconRed","iconBlue", "iconGreen", "iconOrange"];
    var sizeScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1, 2, 3,4]).range(size);
    var fontColorScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1, 2, 3,4]).range(fontColor);

var y_position = 420;
    race_frequency_array.forEach(function(element){
      graph1.append("text")
      .attr("id", "raceLabel")
      .attr("x", xPadding)
      .attr("y", y_position)
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .attr("alignment-baseline", "hanging")
      .style("font-size", sizeScale(element.RowNum) + "px")
      .classed(fontColorScale(element.RowNum), true)
      .text("70,000 people injured were white");
      y_position += sizeScale(element.RowNum)+10;
    });
```

Comment: Wrap the text you want to colour in a span, give that span a class, target the class in CSS to change the colour.

Comment: @sol I know in HTML, it would be `<text><span class="red">70,000</span> people injured were <span class="red>white</span></text>`. But how do I do that in D3? B/c `append` only makes a child element. There's no way to `append` 2 span elements in a text element in 1 line...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `foreignObject` is an option but I'd not recommend that. Instead, I found the time to actually code it for you and make it pretty dynamic as well. I'm using `tspan`s and that's how to ***segregate*** texts within a long text and style them individually (this is an approach recommended by Mike as well). Look at how I'm defining the array which makes it pretty dynamic to change the color as well.

**Here's a code snippet:**

```js
var size = [60,50,40,30];
    var fontColor = ["iconRed","iconBlue", "iconGreen", "iconOrange"];
    var sizeScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1, 2, 3,4]).range(size);
    var fontColorScale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([1, 2, 3,4]).range(fontColor);

var race_frequency_array = [
 [
   {text: '70%', color: '#d9534f'}, 
    {text: ' of people killed were '}, 
    {text: 'BLACK', color: '#d9534f'}
  ],
  [
   {text: '20%', color: '#5bc0de'}, 
    {text: ' of people killed were '}, 
    {text: 'WHITE', color: '#5bc0de'}
  ],
  [
   {text: '7%', color: '#5cb85c'}, 
    {text: ' of people killed were '}, 
    {text: 'LATINO', color: '#5cb85c'}
  ],
  [
   {text: '3%', color: '#f0ad4e'}, 
    {text: ' of people killed were '}, 
    {text: 'ASIAN', color: '#f0ad4e'}
  ]  
];

var graph1 = d3.select('svg')
       .append('g').attr('class', 'texts');
var xPadding = 10, y_position = 0;
      var texts = graph1.selectAll('text').data(race_frequency_array)
        .enter().append("text")
        .attr("id", "raceLabel");
          
     texts     
      .attr("x", xPadding)
      .attr("y", function(d, i) {
       y_position += sizeScale(i)+10;
       return y_position; 
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .attr("alignment-baseline", "hanging")
      .style("font-size", function(d, i) { return sizeScale(i) + "px"});
      
      var tspans = texts.selectAll('tspan')
              .data(function(d) { return d; });
      tspans.enter()
       .append('tspan')
        .style('fill', function(d) { return d.color; })
        .style('font-weight', '600')
        .text(function(d) { return d.text; });
                      
    //  y_position += sizeScale(element.RowNum)+10;
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<svg width="1200" height="400"></svg>
```

The code is easily understandable BUT if you're stuck at something that you don't get, do get back to me. Hope it helps. :)